# python compare two excel sheet and append correct record

Tags: python, excel, sorting, comparison

I need to create an excel sheet comparing two sample sheets one contains the serial number and other information. Second sheet contains the warranty date. For example,
source1 sheet contains data as below

```
Model       Serial     Location
Dell        1234       A
Thoshiba    2345       B
Apple       3456       C
Cisco       4567       D
Sun         5678       E
```

source2 contains data as below

```
Serial  Warranty Status
2345    1/1/2010
4567    2/2/2012
1112    3/2/2015
```

and the result should be

```
Model        Serial     Location    Warranty Status
Dell         1234           A        Not Found
Thoshiba     2345           B        1/1/2010
Apple        3456           C        Not Found
Cisco        4567           D        2/2/2012
Sun          5678           E        Not Found
Not Found    1112          Not Found    3/2/2015
```

I have found some sample scripts but my scenario contains:

1. Large no of data, it takes so much time to run
2. Serial number doesn't comes in the same order in both source1 and source2 files
3. Cases are there in which serial number doeskin exist in either of the source file

Please give me some suggestions and best algorithm to do this faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the below code, which I modified :

```
import pandas as pd

source1_df = pd.read_excel('a.xlsx', sheetname='source1')
source2_df = pd.read_excel('a.xlsx', sheetname='source2')
joined_df = pd.merge(source1_df,source2_df,on='Serial',how='outer')
joined_df.to_excel('/home/user1/test/result.xlsx')
```

I'm not an expert in python but above one worked.

Answer (score 0):

Install [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.0/), then you can load each sheet as a dataframe and join by the `Serial`:

```
import pandas as pd

source1_df = pd.read_excel('path/to/excel', sheetname='source1_sheet_name')
source2_df = pd.read_excel('path/to/excel', sheetname='source2_sheet_name')

joined_df = source1_df.join(source2_df, on='Serial')

joined_df.to_excel('path/to/output_excel')
```

Comment: getting some errors for this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38347985/python-pandas-merging-excel-sheets-not-working