# python pandas merging excel sheets not working

Tags: excel, pandas, python-3.5

I'm trying to merge two excel sheets using the common filed Serial but throwing some errors. My program is as below :

```
 (user1_env)root@ubuntu:~/user1/test/compare_files# cat compare.py
import pandas as pd

source1_df = pd.read_excel('a.xlsx', sheetname='source1')
source2_df = pd.read_excel('a.xlsx', sheetname='source2')
joined_df = source1_df.join(source2_df, on='Serial')

joined_df.to_excel('/root/user1/test/compare_files/result.xlsx')
```

getting error as below :

```
    (user1_env)root@ubuntu:~/user1/test/compare_files# python3.5 compare.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "compare.py", line 5, in <module>
    joined_df = source1_df.join(source2_df, on='Serial')
  File "/home/user1/miniconda3/envs/user1_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4385, in join
    rsuffix=rsuffix, sort=sort)
  File "/home/user1/miniconda3/envs/user1_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4399, in _join_compat
    suffixes=(lsuffix, rsuffix), sort=sort)
  File "/home/user1/miniconda3/envs/user1_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/tools/merge.py", line 39, in merge
    return op.get_result()
  File "/home/user1/miniconda3/envs/user1_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/tools/merge.py", line 223, in get_result
    rdata.items, rsuf)
  File "/home/user1/miniconda3/envs/user1_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 4445, in items_overlap_with_suffix
    to_rename)
ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['Serial'], dtype='object')
```

I'm referring below SO link for the issue :
[python compare two excel sheet and append correct record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38301076/python-compare-two-excel-sheet-and-append-correct-record/38301158#38301158)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small modification worked for me,

```
import pandas as pd

source1_df = pd.read_excel('a.xlsx', sheetname='source1')
source2_df = pd.read_excel('a.xlsx', sheetname='source2')
joined_df = pd.merge(source1_df,source2_df,on='Serial',how='outer')
joined_df.to_excel('/home/gk/test/result.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because of the overlapping column names after join. You can either set your index to `Serial` and join, or specify a `rsuffix=` or `lsuffix=` value in your `join` function so that the suffix value would be appended to the common column names.